# Keycloak container ignoring DB_ADDR option

Tags: mysql, docker, keycloak

I am trying to create a docker container for keycloak using a remote MySQL db.
For some reason the DB_ADDR option seem to be ignored during startup and Keycloak keeps trying to connect to a unexpected address and I'm getting the below error :

> at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'keycloakuser'@'192.168.0.254' (using password: YES)

> FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database

Not sure where this ip address (192.168.0.254) comes from and why Keycloak is ignoring the ip address I provide with the option DB_ADDR

Here is the command I use :

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e DB_VENDOR=mysql -e DB_ADDR=<ip_address> -e DB_PORT=3306 -e DB_DATABASE=keycloakdb -e DB_USER=keycloakuser -e DB_PASSWORD=password jboss/keycloak
```

Comment: try instead: --db=mysql --db-url=<JDBC-URL> --db-username=<DB-USER> --db-password=<DB-PASSWORD>

Comment: @HamzaTahiri that is a syntax for Keycloak 17+. `jboss/keycloak:latest` image is only 16.1.1 at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, it was a network misconfiguration on the MySQL server side. Sorry and thanks for your suggestions guys.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, can you please tell me what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that DB_ADDR is not a valid environmental variable in current versions of keycloak. As per the documentation [here](https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers) and [here](https://www.keycloak.org/server/db), the correct environmental variables are all prefixed `KC_`, and some of them have changed entirely (e.g. `DB_ADDR` has become `KC_DB_URL_HOST`). So for instance, one valid configuration might be `KC_DB_URL=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/keycloak`.

The "relevant options" section at the bottom of the two documentation pages shows the (somewhat confusing) mapping between the CLI arguments you would pass to the container, vs the environmental variables you could define for the container.

Keycloak has some example docker-compose files [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/main/docker-compose-examples/keycloak-mysql.yml) that show up on Google and that I suspect are making the confusion worse, but if you check the repository homepage you will see that the repository is archived and only valid for older versions of Keycloak.

Making things even worse, if the incorrect variables are passed Keycloak will silently ignore them and default to using localhost which in many docker deployments may be a valid network address for the backing database. You can test for sure whether your variables are being used by specifying unique invalid addresses for the different variables (e.g. `DB_ADDR=ThisDoesntExist_1`) and checking which one Keycloak complains about in stdout / docker logs.

In this particular case, you might try one of these two possible approaches. Using environmental variables, you might try this:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e KC_DB=mysql -e KC_DB_URL_HOST=<ip_address> -e KC_DB_URL_PORT=3306 -e KC_DB_URL_DATABASE=keycloakdb -e KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloakuser -e KC_DB_PASSWORD=password jboss/keycloak
```

And if you prefer command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 jboss/keycloak --DB=mysql --DB_URL_HOST=<ip_address> --DB_URL_PORT=3306 --DB_URL_DATABASE=keycloakdb --DB_USERNAME=keycloakuser --DB_PASSWORD=password
```